# HTML page does not load after clicking href, but after a reload it does

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, hyperlink, routes

My href does not work. The link of the href shows up correctly in the browser (Chrome), but no page is rendered. After clicking the refresh button in the browser, the page renders correctly.

I don´t know if this is important, but I generate the href-link with a helper, which is a MongoDB array.

**Here is my data:**

```
{
    "_id" : "n8usBgSfG8NQRwRxD",
    "linkGenerator" : [ 
        "ABC(8f6b1d521b7bd452)", 
        "ABC(c1348b440c15ec52)"
    ],
}
```

**Here is my helper:**

```
Template.link.helpers({ 
  'unts': function() {
   if (Meteor.userId()) {
  var a = userManagement.find().fetch();

    return a;
  }
},

});
```

**Here is my HTML:**

```
 {{#each unts}}
        <ul class="list-group">
        {{#each linkGenerator}}
            <li class="list-group-item">


<a href= "localhost:3000/link/{{this}}" target="_blank"> <span class="nav-label"></span>{{this}}</a>

            </li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
    {{/each}}
```

**And here is my route (iron router):**

```
Router.route('/link/:opened',{

  waitOn: function() {
  var params = this.params;
  Session.set('opened', params.opened);
  },

  action: function() {
  this.render('link');
  this.layout('blankLayout');
},

});
```

I just don't know why it does not work, when I click on the href, but works fine when I than refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Does not seem to be a "worthwhile" topic...

However, I was stuck for hours before I found the solution. Therefore here is the way how I got it to work:

I replaced the full link in the href with only the fragment "/link/{{this}}" of it. Therefore the rest worked fine and it was just the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that

```
<button
    type="button"
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.href='http://google.com';
      }}
>CLICK ME</button>
```